# Difference between java.util.logging.Logger and java.lang.System.Logger

Tags: java, logging, java-9

Java 9 introduced a new logger, namely [`java.lang.System.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.Logger.html) but we always had [`java.util.logging.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

What's new with this logger and how it is better?

Comment: Java 9 introduces [modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), and the [`System.LoggerFinder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html) ***elaborates*** on your included links and says *The system default `LoggerFinder` implementation uses `java.util.logging` as the backend framework when the `java.logging` module is present.* To your question, when the `java.logging` module is **not** present, it cannot use `java.util.logging.Logger`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I understood you correctly, since `java.logging` module is not part of `java.base` we don't want to introduce a dependency when we don't plan to use it as the backend. Am I correct?

Comment: What will happen if not `java.logging` or any other 3rd party logging module is present, will it fail? EDIT: I just read your link, it will forward to `System.err`

Comment: I would assume so, but I haven't tried it. Of course, it's also possible to override the default and use some other logging framework (which is presumably better).

Comment: Thanks for your info. Please post it as an answer, it might benefit future users.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While there might be subtle differences between them, the most important difference is that `System.Logger` (in `java.base` module) is a *facade*, while `java.util.logging.Logger` (in `java.logging`) is an *implementation*.

The core idea behind this is for library authors to write dependency free logging in their code and let every user of that library provide their favorite implementation. It also means your whole application will use the same logging framework instead of having to tune the logger of each and every library in your codebase.

Since JDK 9 it is possible to not have `java.logging` in the module-graph, which really frees you to use any implementation you wish without even having useless packages in the JDK image. In case `java.logging` is present, it's used as the default backend unless a different backend is present. If no backend is present, it will just print to `System.err`.

Answer (score 14):

- `java.lang.System.Logger` is defined in Module [`java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.logging-summary.html)
  while `java.util.logging.Logger` is defined in Module
  [`java.logging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.logging-summary.html)
- External framework support such as SLF4J or Log4J is enhanced.
- Capability to deal with bootstrap issues, so that platform classes
  can log messages before the log consumer is initialized.

The logging Levels are changes quite a different as compared to `util.logging.Logger`:

```
+--------------------------+-----+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+-----+
|   System.Logger Levels   | ALL | TRACE | DEBUG | INFO | WARNING | ERROR  | OFF |
+--------------------------+-----+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+-----+
| java.util.logging Levels | ALL | FINER | FINE  | INFO | WARNING | SEVERE | OFF |
+--------------------------+-----+-------+-------+------+---------+--------+-----+
```

---

If you want to know the motivation behind `java.lang.System.Logger` , I strongly advise you to read [**JEP 264: Platform Logging API and Service**](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/264)